# listView shows all data instead of just what I specified

Tags: android, listview, adapter

So The problem I'm having is that I have a hashtable with the key values being

Key: Integer
Value: ArrayList

In my custom listView adapter I have it set to only display the values at a certain position in the hashtable..but at the moment it's displaying the entire hashtable. I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong.. Here's the adapter

Note: Statics.mainPageListPosition is a static int that gets set when the user clicks on a certain position on the main screen. I want the adapter then to display that position, and only that position's data.

```
package assignments;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Hashtable;

import com.example.mt_study.R;
import com.example.statics.Statics;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AssignmentListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Assignment> {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Hashtable<Integer, ArrayList<Assignment>> assignmentList;

    // class used to hold views when the user scrolls on the listView
    // it stores them and then we can re-use their id's as the user scrolls
    // down or up the screen so we don't have to keep calling findViewById
    private class assignmentViewHolder {
        TextView Title;
        TextView Date;

        public assignmentViewHolder(TextView assignmentTitle, TextView Date) {
            this.Title = assignmentTitle;
            this.Date = Date;
        }

        public TextView getTitle() {
            return Title;
        }

        public TextView getDate() {
            return Date;
        }
    }

    public AssignmentListViewAdapter(Context context,
            Hashtable<Integer, ArrayList<Assignment>> data) {
        super(context, R.id.assignment_row_title, R.id.assignment_row_date);
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        assignmentList = data;

    }

    // set of functions useful for the getView function
    public int getCount() {
        return Statics.allAssignments.get(Statics.mainPageListPosition).size();
    }

    public Assignment getItem(int position) {
        return assignmentList.get(Statics.mainPageListPosition).get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Assignment assignment = this.getItem(position);

        TextView assignmentTitle;
        TextView assignmentDate;

        // if theres no view yet created on the screen, create one
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.assignment_row, null);

            // give the views their respective ID's
            assignmentTitle = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.assignment_row_title);
            assignmentDate = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.assignment_row_date);

            // set the tag so we can just use the viewHolder instead of calling
            // findViewById over. It saves memory
            convertView.setTag(new assignmentViewHolder(assignmentTitle,
                    assignmentDate));
        }
        // this gets called when the user scrolls down or up the screen and the
        // adapter
        // wants to maximize efficiency by just calling the viewHolder instead
        // of findViewById
        else {
            assignmentViewHolder viewHolder = (assignmentViewHolder) convertView
                    .getTag();
            assignmentTitle = viewHolder.getTitle();
            assignmentDate = viewHolder.getDate();

        }
        // down here is where you set the values for all your views/objects
        // such as Buttons or textViews.
        assignmentTitle.setText(Statics.allAssignments
                .get(Statics.mainPageListPosition).get(position).getTitle());
        assignmentDate.setText(Statics.allAssignments
                .get(Statics.mainPageListPosition).get(position).getDate_due());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Edit: recent discovery, that my hashtable puts every value I send it in every position available lol. What I do is when the user clicks on a position on the main page it saves that position and uses it to store the data they save at that position in the hashtable. Temp is an arrayList with the user's saved data stored in this format :

{number, String, number, string}
Where the number is the position in the hashtable I want to store the string.

Here is where I'm saving the data to the hashtable. Everything looks right to me, maybe i've been staring at it too long @.@

```
for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++) {
                if (isInteger(temp.get(i))) {
                    currentAssignment.setTitle(temp.get(i + 1));
                    //currentAssignment.setDate_due(temp.get(i + 2));
                    currentAssignmentList.add(index, currentAssignment);
                    index++;

                    Statics.allAssignments.put(Integer.parseInt(temp.get(i)), currentAssignmentList);
                    //Statics.allAssignments.get(Integer.parseInt(temp.get(i))).add(currentAssignment);
                    currentAssignment = new Assignment();
                    //Toast.makeText(context, "Called" + Integer.toString(i), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where are you setting the list of items on the ArrayAdapter? I think you should use your `data` constructor parameter, either with `addAll(data)` or in your call to `super()`. Note that you currently ignore this data in `getView()` and use your statics instead. In `getView()`, once you have items correctly set in the superclass ArrayAdapter, you should use `Assignment a = getItem(position)` and set your fields from this object instead of your statics.

E.g. in the constructor...

```
super(context, R.id.assignment_row_title, R.id.assignment_row_date, data);
```

Then in getView()...

```
Assignment a = getItem(position);
assignmentTitle.setText(a.getTitle());
assignmentDate.setText(a.getDate_due());
```

This of course assumes that the list you pass in as `data` is correct. Hopefully once you have your code looking at only one list of items you can more easily verify that this list is correct.

**Edit:**

In your second chunk of code, where do you make a new `currentAssignmentList` for each hash table key? If you assign the same object to all entries your hash table, then they will all contain the same list.

Comment: This just seems like moving the data around rather than fixing things..?? Is there significance to this?
Also I just found out that my hashtable somehow is putting everything in every position...

Comment: Well I can't see how the original code even works without you telling the array adapter what the array is. Also I'd discourage using globals (statics) in any case. (And it seems that my suspicion about the validity of your ArrayList data was correct ;-)

Comment: (Added a response to your second chunk of code -- see edit above.)

Comment: derppppppp.. I see the problem now. Fixing time :) Ty!

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to call `notifyDataSetChanged` on your `adapter` when you change the `mainPageListPosition` value.